# Taking off ellipsis in css

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am developing a timetable application, I am looking the Activity_Date to only display the start as it is passed through with both the date and the time. But when I use this code is used it cuts the time off but displays an ellipsis, any help to get rid of the ellipsis would be appreciated, thanks.

css:

```
.mydate{
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 6em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

html:

```
<ion-content>
        <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
        <div class="day">

            <div class="item item-divider item-divider-calm item-icon icon-left">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-alarm-outline"> Monday</i>
            </div>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-show="item.Location" ng-repeat="item in test | filter: {Day: 'Mon'}" class="item item-list ">
                    <table style="width:300px; table-layout:fixed;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Course
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: pre-line;">{{item.Register_Description}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Tutor
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: pre-line;">{{item.Staff_Name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Campus
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: pre-line;">{{item.Campus}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Location
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: pre-line;">{{item.Location}}</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Date
                            </td>
                            <td><p class="mydate">{{item.Activity_Date.date}}</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Start Time
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: pre-line;">{{item.Activity_Start_Time}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                End Time
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: pre-line;">{{item.Activity_End_Time}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Timetabled Hours
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: pre-line;">{{item.Timetabled_Hours}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Register
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space: pre-line;">{{item.Register}}</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </div>
```

Json:

```
 [{
"StudentID": "",
"Course": "",
"Module": "",
"Activity_Start_Time": "",
"Activity_End_Time": "",
"Activity_Date": {
    "date": "2016-04-14 00:00:00.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "UTC"
},
"Activity_Type": "",
"Day": "",
"Campus": "",
"Location": "",
"Staff_Name": "",
"Register_Description": "",
"Timetabled_Hours": 2
}]
```

How date is passed through:
2015-09-16 00:00:00.000

Current output:
2015-09-16...

Desired output:
2015-09-16 or 16-09-2015

Comment: Remove the `text-overflow: clip;` rule.

Comment: This returned the previous output when done

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want ellipsis then just remove `text-overflow` property

```
.mydate{
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 6em;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

> In you css `text-overflow` were generating ellipsis effect by removing it the ellipsis effect will remove and the text will show till the defined width

Comment: I have tried this, but no changes seemed to be made on the output

Comment: can you create a fiddle with the problem or post you html code

Comment: working fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/qe43ku7o/1/. Make sure any other property is not coming from some other code

Comment: I have just checked the data in which I am pulling in the Activity_Date seems to be an array of date and two timezone variables. Don't suppose that could have something to do with it?

Comment: {"date":"2016-04-19 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"} This is how the Activity_Date is stored